# Catch error not work in javascript

Tags: javascript

Y this code doesn't work with me? , i did all steps , so any one plz tell me where is my fault , and thank u

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction()
 {
    try
    {
        var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;
        if(x=="")    throw="empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw"not a number";
        if(x>10)     throw"too high";
        if(x<5)      throw"too low";
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        var y=document.getElementById("mess");
        y.innerHTML="Error:" + err + ".";
    }
}
</script>
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p>Please input a number between 5 and 10:</p>
<input id="demo" type="text" />
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Test input</button>
<p id="mess"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have included an `=` incorrectly in your `throw` statement here,

```
 if(x=="")    throw="empty";
```

just remove it and try.

**Here is the working fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/74suvvfq/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function() {
  try {
    var x=document.getElementById("demo").value;
    if(x=="")    throw "empty";
    if(isNaN(x)) throw  "not a number";
    if(x>10)     throw "too high";
    if(x<5)      throw "too low";
 }
 catch(err) {
    var y=document.getElementById("mess");
    y.innerHTML="Error:" + err + ".";
}
});
```

Hope this will help